# Strange behviour with java example

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Why this program is running without giving any compilation error ?

```
public class test 
{
  public static void main(String javalatte[])
   {
     http://google.com/
     System.out.println("test");
   }
}
```

http://ideone.com/hc3i0d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `http:` is a [label](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) (yes there are labels in Java)
- `//` and following is an inline comment

Comment: Oops yes you are correct, how can i forgot that thing..:)

Comment: The link that explains what a label is, is something entirely different than what the word "label" means in this context.

Comment: @Jesper thanks, edited. I was too quick and didn't pay attention.

Comment: It is worth noticing that label needs to actually label something (comments doesn't count) so without `System.out.println("test");` this code would not compile.

Comment: @Pshemo +1 to your comment. It's also explained in the linked documentation article (now that I got the link right, that is :).

Answer (score 2):

`http:` is considered as [label](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) and `//google.com/` is comment as its preceded by `//` (*Which is used for single line comment*).

Answer (score 1):

That is because the part `http:` is treated as a label in java, and the following statement `//google.com/` is treated as a single line comment .